# Binding SelectedItem of ListView inside of DataTemplate

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, listview, uwp

I'm currently working on a music player app and I'm getting stuck on keeping the playing track highlighted in all ListViews in the app.

For example, there is a page with a list of albums, each of which contains a DataTemplate with a [list of songs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly6kD.png). All is well and good when you first select it and the selected item is bound to the viewmodel. But on navigating away from and the returning to that page, the viewmodel retains the information about which sing was playing, [but the binding doesn't cause the item to be highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVKiM.png).

Here is my XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstSongs"
    ItemsSource="{Binding attachments}"
    SelectionChanged="lstSongs_SelectionChanged"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
    SelectedValue="{Binding DataContext.selectedSong, ElementName=Group_Page}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.selectedSong, ElementName=Group_Page}"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewTextHighlight}"
    Grid.Row="1">
```

Binding the SelectedItem and SelectedValue was just to see if either one would work.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but nevertheless I hope someone can help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: There's usually no reason to bind a "SelectedItem/Value" to the view model, why not bind to the element directly?
Though I don't quit understand the question, that could be one thing that could help you.
Another question - what's exactly in your data context? any reason you're binding to a page's datacontext and not having one for the view itself?

Comment: @MichaelThePotato I'm not quite sure I follow about binding to the element directly. What do you mean?

As for why I'm binding to the page's viewmodel, the listview's default viewmodel is the parent listview, so it doesn't expose the relevant field where I can retrieve the current song

Answer (score 2):

I think the `SelectedItem` binding needs to be `Mode=TwoWay`

```
SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.selectedSong, ElementName=Group_Page, Mode=TwoWay }"
```

Comment: The only thing that I would add is that this isn't the only issue that could be happening. If the thing he's attempting to bind the SelectedItem to isn't 1. a property and 2. of the correct data type it won't work either.

Comment: Damn, I was hoping he moonlighted as an engineer in his free time.